# JSF 2: Help with logic programming

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

i have this menu:

```
<ul class="lavaLamp" id="menu">
    <li><a href="./index.xhtml" >Home</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="#">Company</a>
    //..
</ul>
```

I want this menu be a component, so i don't have to copy and paste in every .xhtml page.
But i need to specify the class field in the `<li>` tag, so the plugin '[LavaLamp](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/)' can be applied.

E.g: the current page is index.xhtml so it should generate:

```
<ul class="lavaLamp" id="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="./index.xhtml" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a>
    //..
</ul>
```

I'm thinking how do this but nothing came out.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @meriton talk about EL, i searched about it and found something about EL ternary, so this is my solution:

```
<ul class="lavaLamp" id="menu">
    <li class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId == '/index.xhtml' ? 'current' : '' }"><a href="index.xhtml" >Home</a></li>
    <li class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId == '/pages/company/team.xhtml' ? 'current' : '' }"><a href="pages/company/team.xhtml" >Team</a></li>
    //..
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My first refactoring would be:

```
<ul class="lavaLamp" id="menu">
    <li class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId = 'index.html' ? 'current' : ''"><a href="./index.xhtml" >Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Company</a>
    //..
</ul>
```

(the global el variable `facesContext` always points to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()`)

Comment: it launch this exception:javax.servlet.ServletException: /resources/components/top.xhtml 23,96 class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId = 'index.html' ? 'current' : ''" EL Expression Unbalanced: ... #{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId = 'index.html' ? 'current' : ''

Comment: it was missing a '}', e.g: <li class="#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId} = 'index.xhtml' ? 'current' : ''"><a href="./index.xhtml" >Home</a></li>